# Object detection evaluation model main error

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm currently working ona object detection model efficientnet and i tried to evaluate my mode with model main but got the error

ValueError: Tensor("Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/0:0", shape=(), dtype=string) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Loss/TargetAssignment/AvgNumGroundtruthBoxesPerImage:0", shape=(), dtype=string) (graphs are FuncGraph(name=cond_true_48273, id=139640549532432) and <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f0111ca0410>).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by passing the checkpoint file path correctly, e.g.:
`--checkpoint_dir=/checkpoint/ckpt-x`, where x is the checkpoint number. Also check for this bug https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/5450. It worked for me.